# No block node found with @name="wholesale.grid"

Tags: magento-1.7, varnish, turpentine

I'm trying to add a block to product pages by way of my theme's local.xml file, only to have turpentine blow up.

Here's the relevant local.xml (which works if I omit the `setEsiOptions`):

```
...
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="wholesale.grid" as="wholesale_grid" template="wholesale/wholesalegrid.phtml">
            <action method="setEsiOptions">
                <params>
                    <access>customer_group</access>
                    <registry_keys>
                        <current_product/>
                    </registry_keys>
                </params>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
...
```

When the `setEsiOptions` action is omitted, the proper content is displayed.  When it's included, the following shows up in the error logs:

```
2015-12-21T21:19:46+00:00 WARN (4): TURPENTINE: No block node found with @name="wholesale.grid"
```

[Here's a link to the line responsible in Turpentine](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/blob/35d44f51e84de419c189eea2baa0ec89c7a2ba39/app/code/community/Nexcessnet/Turpentine/controllers/EsiController.php#L217)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found a bug in Turpentine! Or at least a case that isn't handled correctly.

I was using the `System -> Design` override for this store view which trickles through to `layout`.

Turpentine can see the block on the way out and correctly makes the decision to encode the data based on the `esiOptions` present.  When the request comes back to turpentine by way of Ajax or Varnish, it can't find the block by name because it doesn't take `System -> Design` layout xml overrides into account.

Once I changed the `layout` defined in `System -> Configuration -> Design -> Layout` for that store view, the problem was resolved.

Comment: Thanks for opening an issue on the github so we can resolve this as need be :)